# How to change this code from recursion to iteration

Tags: c++

I've trying to make the following code implement by iteration instead of recursive(the "hit" function of the BVH_node class),but I've no idea how to do this.I did found some topic about this,but they are not very helpful.Could anybody help me?thanks so much.(by the way this is the third time I ask this question ,people says that I'm not making my question clear,please give me some advice on asking question)

```
class Ray {
public:
    vec3 origin;
    vec3 direction;
    float t = 10000.0f;
};
class AABB{
public:
bool hit(Ray ray){
//test if ray hit itself
//but don't write the t into the ray
}
vec3 min;
vec3 max;
};

class Geometry {
public:
    bool hit(Ray& ray) {
        float t;
        //test if the ray hit this geometry
        //ray.origin + t * ray.direction = ......
        //then solve the t
        if (t < ray.t && t>0.0f) {
            ray.t = t;
            return true;
        }

            return false;
    }

private:
    //...some private data
};

class BVH_node {
public:
    void construction(/*......some data for construction*/) {
        //is_node_or_geo = ......
        //if(is_node_or_geo == 0)
        //L_node = ......; R_node = ......;
        //if(is_node_or_geo == 1)
        //L_geo = ......; R_geo = ......;
    }
    bool hit(Ray& ray) {
        if(aabb.hit(ray)){
        if (is_node_or_geo == 0) {
            bool hit_left = L_node->hit(ray);
            bool hit_right = R_node->hit(ray);
            return hit_left || hit_right;
        }
        if (is_node_or_geo == 1) {
            bool hit_left = L_geo->hit(ray);
            bool hit_right = R_geo->hit(ray);
            return hit_left || hit_right;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
private:
    int is_node_or_geo;//node = 0,geo = 1
    AABB aabb;
    BVH_node* L_node;
    BVH_node* R_node;
    Geometry* L_geo;
    Geometry* R_geo;
};

int main(){
    BVH_node* root = new BVH_node;
    root->construction(/*.......*/);
    Ray ray;//ray = .......;
    bool hit = root->hit(ray);
    delete root;
}
```

most tutorial I found on how to change recursion to iteration(like this http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html) don't consider some situation where member variable is involved.

Comment: Unrelated: `hit` fails horribly if `if (aabb.hit(ray))` is false.

Comment: No shame in having trouble untangling the recursion in this sucker, but you'll strengthen your question quite a bit by showing your best attempt.

Comment: Question seems clear enough to me, although you could link to the other topic you found, and explain why you found it unhelpful.

Comment: Considering that the current code is bugged (see user4581301's comment) it hard to know what to advise until that bug is fixed.

Comment: I should have fixed the bugs,the code I written there is just for example use,I just want to make things easiler:)

Comment: There's no general process for changing recursion to iteration. But the basic idea is that you have to implement your own data structures to keep track of all the pending computations, to replace the stack of function calls. It's not usually as easy as going from iteration to recursion.

Comment: @Barmar could you please give me a simple example on how to "create my own stack and keep track of pending computaion"?I got no idea on how to do this.thanks

Comment: It'd be easier to provide a full answer with a [mre] but basically make a `std::stack<BVH_node*>` and instead of recursing push to the stack. At the start of each iteration through a loop pop a node from the stack and process it, repeat until the stack is empty

Comment: @dsukrect Don't you think the whole point of the exercise was for you to try to figure it out, isn't that how you learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow up on the approach mentioned in a comment of *Alan Birtles*:

Let us focus on the `hit` function. In order to make our life easier, it's better to first rewrite it as follows:

```
bool hit(Ray& ray) {
    if(!aabb.hit(ray)) return false;

    if (is_node_or_geo == 0) {
        if (L_node->hit(ray)) return true;
        if (R_node->hit(ray)) return true;
        return false;

    } else if (is_node_or_geo == 1) {
        if (L_geo->hit(ray)) return true;
        if (R_geo->hit(ray)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now we can add a loop and a stack (implemented with a `std::vector`, since I'm not familiar with `std::stack`). We also make the method `static`, as it does not relate to a single object:

```
static bool hit(Ray& ray, BVH_node * root) {

    std::vector<BVH_node *> nodes {root};

    while (!nodes.empty()){
        BVH_node & top = *nodes.back();
        nodes.pop_back();

        if(!top.aabb.hit(ray)) continue;

        if (top.is_node_or_geo == 0) {
            nodes.push_back(top.L_node);
            nodes.push_back(top.R_node);
            continue;

        } else if (top.is_node_or_geo == 1) {
            if (top.L_geo->hit(ray)) return true;
            if (top.R_geo->hit(ray)) return true;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code wasn't tested so it might require minor tweacking.

Note that depending on your implementation, you might want to add a bunch of `const`s - after every mention of `BVH_node`

Comment: @dsukrect If this answers your question, consider accepting it.

Comment: @Benny K,thanks so much,your answer is very helpful,It work,and much faster than the recursive version!

Comment: @dsukrect Regarding the running time - the benefit of makin this iterative v.s. recursive is probably negligible. I bet the first (recursive) version in my answer is also faster than yours, simply because of the short-circuit of some branches. For example, if `L_node->hit(ray) == true` there's no need to calculate `R_node->hit(ray)`.

Comment: @Benny K,I'm using gpu(Cuda),where recursion could be way more slow,It was about 5 times slower than the iteration version,and compiler can't decide the stack size statically when recursion is used,I have to set it manually.And I think R_node->hit(ray) is necessary there since I need the "t" in the ray(the ray is pass by reference,and modified in the Geometry::hit(Ray& ray).

Comment: Then note that if `ray` is modified on "dead" branches (that eventually return `false` in your recursive version), my solution will lead to different results.